# After installing MS SQL Server 2012 not able to log into SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows

Okay, lot's of posts around the internet on this subject. But I haven't been able to find an answer I was looking for. I installed SQLS 2012 on Windows Server 2012. I installed the Engine and the Reporting Server. In the Database Engine Configuration I just checked Windows Authentication Mode and specified a Security Group I created on the AD as the SQL Server Administrators.

I log in to the SQL Server with an account that is Domain Admin and a member of the SQL Server Adminsitrators group. When I open SSMS I can login to the Reporting Services using Windows credentials, but are not able to contact the Database Engine. Login failed for user 'MYDOM\myadminuser' Reason: Could not fund a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]

1. I see a lot of tips saying: "Use mixed mode instead of Windows authentication mode". Where can I change that if I cannot access the Database Engine with SSMS.
2. Followup: I want to authenticate only users known in the AD. Why would I need mixed mode?

Comment: If you are unable to login to the database engine, you will need to rip it out and reinstall using Mixed auth. Mixed auth is good for initial testing and setup in case you are unable to login with win auth.

Comment: Come on, there's got to be a way to reconfigure this. And, as said, I really don't want mixed mode! So why should I test it?

Comment: I've never seen a way to get into an instance you are basically locked out of besides uninstalling.

Comment: You can try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx
But if you are locked out of the engine, for whatever reason, there usually isn't a way to get back in.

Comment: I haven't been locked out as in I was able to login but my account got locked. I have a vanilla installation wheere something is wrong that needs to be solved from my point of view.

Comment: If your account is locked, you are locked out. What am I missing here?

Comment: The explanation how this happend. I can reinstall, but that will lead to the same problem unless I select mixed mode, I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably 3 years too late, but others may benefit. There is normally a security in place for SQL server that if you are logged into the server as domain admin, you have to start up SQL Management Studio with a Run As Administrator option. If you start up SQL Management Studio "normally" it won't let you log in BECAUSE you are Domain Admin.

Sysadmin Guy

Comment: Sounds like a logical answer. :) Cannot verify this anymore. But thanks anyway!